# Grails spring security signup with moderation

Tags: java, spring, authentication, grails, spring-security

Is it possible in grails spring security to allow the signup attempts to be first approved by moderator?
If yes, then I can't seem to figure it out in the docs. So how do I do it?
If no, then what is the way to go about it? What other plugin will provide this feature built into itself. As a standard I would prefer going the spring security way. But if that's not possible, then will have to go for what is possible.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a User object that defaults `enabled` to false like this (make sure you can't set enabled from the client):

```
class User {
    // ...
    boolean enabled = false
    // ....
}
```

Then have a moderator protected view that can enable users. [Spring Security UI](https://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-ui) would be able to do this part.